# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string Typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a table filled with DateTime values in the format of `2022-12-08` in a field called date.
I got all the values with `findAll()` function but I can't display the date value event by using

```
<div class="event-date"><f:format.date format="%d %B %Y">{event.date}</f:format.date></div>
```

[image: i've tried this code]

---

my tca:

```
'date' => [ 
   'exclude' => true, 
   'label' => 'LLL:EXT:events/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_events_domain_model_event.date', 
   'config' => [ 
      'dbType' => 'date', 
      'type' => 'input', 
      'renderType' => 'inputDateTime', 
      'size' => 7, 
      'eval' => 'date', 
      'default' => null, 
   ], 
],
```

---

my model:

```
/**
     * Returns the date
     *
     * @return \DateTime $date
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        $date = $this->date;
    if($date) {
        $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    }
    return $date;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return void
     */
    public function setDate(\DateTime $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }
```

Comment: How is your tca definition of this field and how it is declared inside the extbase model?

Comment: i declared it as DateTime in my model and that's my tca      
   'date' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:events/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_events_domain_model_event.date',
            'config' => [
                'dbType' => 'date',
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'size' => 7,
                'eval' => 'date',
                'default' => null,
            ],
        ],

Comment: Ehm, sure this is because of `f:format.date`-ViewHelper? The VH expects as value an object implementing \DateTimeInterface - and *not* a string.

Comment: i've tried to displayed it without f:format.date but still the same error

Comment: what are your setters and getters for the `date` field? what kind of data do you get in the fluid variables? (use `<f:debug title="event">{event}</f:debug>` inside the loop. (please add your results to your question)